# RVM and Jenkins setup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration, jenkins, rvm

I am new to Jenkins CI. I'm install RVM in my remote Jenkins and when I execute below shell.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
source ~/.bashrc
rvm use 1.9.3@rails-3.2.3
```

I get following errors.

```
+ source /var/lib/jenkins/.bashrc
++ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/bin:/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/bin
+ rvm use 1.9.3@rails-3.2.3

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.
```

What does it mean? I don't have any idea. Please help me.

**UPDATED:** I'm tried below script but I still get errors:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
source /home/zeck/.bashrc
[[ -s ".rvmrc" ]] && source .rvmrc
export RAILS_ENV=test
bundle install
```

Errors:

```
/tmp/hudson457106939700368111.sh: line 5: bundle: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins build shell can't detect RVM, gemsets and gems. What should I do?

**UPDATED 2:** Therefore jenkins can't detect ruby.

```
+ ruby -v
/tmp/hudson2505951775163045158.sh: line 5: ruby: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILUR
```

I'm not using any jenkins plugn and I'm just run script from Build->Execute shell section.

Comment: Zeck, I'm going crazy solving this issue too, how did you fix it???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try:

```
. $(/home/RVM_USER/.rvm/bin/rvm env 1.9.3@rails-3.2.3 --path)
```

make sure you run the stable RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

*NOTE: 
Last Jenkins version does not always accept "source", but ".".
RVM_USER is the user that installed RVM. 
Alternatively you can also export the RVM command in the main PATH.*

Comment: Very first thank you for trying to help. But I get 'rvm: command not found'. Please see my updates

Comment: it's because you use different users for one rvm installation, make sure the second user `zeck` uses the same RVM - in `/home/zeck/.bashrc` add: `export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/bin`

Comment: . $($HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm env --path) worked for me as well.

Answer (score 34):

As the error message suggests, RVM expects an login shell. Changing the hashbang line to `#!/bin/bash -xl` should resolve this.

Comment: By the way, sourcing .rvmrc can print a lot to the terminal. You may want to instead use a `#!/bin/bash -l`, then do `set -x` after sourcing .rvmrc.

Comment: Any explanation of what are -l and -x using for?

Comment: The -l option gives you a login shell, and -x starts bash in debug mode. I was able to use just -l so that the Jenkins output wasn't as verbose.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, apparently you miss the `$HOME/.rvm/bin` in your `PATH`. I am using rvm successfully from Hudson on Mac OS X. First thing to notice is that, unless you define `BASH_ENV` environment variable (`ENV` for sh), `.bashrc` is called automatically only with interactive non-login shell. Such a shell is started when you do - for example - the following from the command line:

```
$ /bin/bash
```

When you use `#!/bin/bash` in your script, `.bashrc` will not be called.

To make rvm work with Hudson, I have the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Thanks to `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` I have rvm enabled every time I start new terminal window (interactive, login shell).

I do not put anything in my `.bashrc`, especially I am not sourcing rvm scripts there. Nothing wrong with that, but if any other scripts makes something stupid like setting `export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc' and then invoke non-interactive shell, you see what may happen - it is actually easy to forget.

Therefore, instead of loading things to your .bashrc, it is better to keep your script independent from any shell startup file and make sure that the correct environment is set up within the script. I still keep `$HOME/.rvm/bin` in my `.bash_profile`, but then I include the following at the beginning of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

rvm use 1.9.3-head@MyGemSet

set -ex
cucumber # just an example
```

Notice the `-e` option which forces the script to exit with error code if any command following `set -ex` fails. This is behavior you may want when using the script with Hudson.
It is incorrect to say that RVM expects a login shell. Although using `#!/bin/bash -l` in your script will work, it does not seem like the best approach.

Comment: Yes, this helped. The location of RVM may differ, in my case it was 
`[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"` which worked, together with `rvm use ruby_name@gemset_name`

Answer (score 3):

Just add this code in your shell script, i think rvm is loading from your source so it should work else need to export PATH variable

```
#!/bin/bash -l
source ~/.bashrc
rvm use 1.9.3@rails-3.2.3
```

l is for login shel, if you include x then it would be for debugging too.

Answer (score 2):

adding a shebang to the build commands in jenkins fixed this for me

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    rvm use 2.0.0
    bundle install
    rake test
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins nodes don't load paths the same way, so it's not using the proper path to find rvm's version of ruby. You can set the path for a given agent.

1. Find your current PATH by doing `echo $PATH`
2. Assuming you've set up rvm properly, find where rvm's version of ruby is located by running `which ruby`
3. There's a setting in the Configuration of your agent where you can set environmental variables. Set PATH to be 1 and 2 concatenated.