# How do I get rvm to use a version without saying is not a function?

Tags: rvm, bash

I realize this have been dealt with here:

[RVM and Jenkins setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209242/rvm-and-jenkins-setup)

But this do not solve the problem for me.

It did before, I put

source $(rvm env 1.9.3@rails-3.2.3 --path)

in my bash_profile and it worked fine until I restarted, then nothing.

Now when I do ruby -v I get:

ruby 1.8.6 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 369) [universal-darwin9.0]

(Leopard's default).

I don't know how to bring it back. Its using the correct rvm set in my bashrc.

When I use rvm use I get:

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.

I go to the URL and it say just put shell -${SHELL} . Which I have done but but no Joy.

Comment: Please somebody answer this soon because I have no working ruby installation on my machine until I fix this.

Comment: you need to go to your terminal settings and enable `login shell` option