# What's gone wrong with my Capistrano configuration?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, capistrano

I'm trying to execute a Capistrano deploy via Jenkins and running into the following build error:

> - cd ~/Sites/MyProject
> - ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/cap production deploy
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in
> 'report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem capistrano (>= 0)
> (Gem::LoadError)
>
> from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in
> 'activate'
>
> from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in
> 'gem'
>
> from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/cap:22
>
> from  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

There's something very suspicious-looking about the switch from Ruby 2.0 to Ruby 1.8 there but I don't know nearly enough about Ruby to know where to start looking... any ideas?

`cap production deploy` works fine from the command line of course.

Comment: Can you see if you have capistrano gem installed in the ruby-2.0.0 . may be run bundle exec cap production deploy

Comment: It looks like I do (to a Ruby newbie like me anyway) - certainly there's a gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/capistrano-3.1.0 folder.  Where would I try running a bundle exec command?

Comment: It seems that you run jenkins from a different user than you think - try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209242/rvm-and-jenkins-setup

Comment: You can run bundle exec from your project root folder.

Comment: Hmm, from the same place that I run `cap production deploy` I can't run bundle exec, there's no Gemfile. Perhaps that's an indication that I'm missing a Gemfile that I should have, I don't know?

Comment: Thank you thank you Uri Agassi!  After some puzzling and false starts I was able to create a successful build using the information contained in that question...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Jenkins to work with the correct version of Ruby by adding the following to my "execute shell command" instructions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/Sites/MyProject
source $(rvm env 2.0.0 --path)
cap production deploy
```