# RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, rvm, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use a version of ruby via RVM in my Jenkinsfile like this:

```
sh 'rvm use ruby 2.3.1'
```

However, I believe the above command isn't doing what is intended because i get this message after it

```
+ rvm use ruby 2.3.1
 RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

I read other answers that suggest adding `#!/bin/bash -xl`, however, I am using this from `Jenkinsfile` and not a bash script.

is there a way to resolve this? I just want to set ruby to 2.3.1 and then run one command.

I've also tried using `create default` but still the version of ruby being printed is 2.0.0

```
  sh '''
    #!/bin/bash -xl
    echo $PATH
    rvm install ruby-2.3.1
    rvm alias create default 2.3.1 && ruby --version
    ruby --version
  '''
```

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209242/rvm-and-jenkins-setup?

Comment: @idej that is the answer I've referenced in my question. This still doesn't explain how to do this from a jenkinsfile.

Comment: Won’t just `bash 'rvm use ruby 2.3.1'` do the trick?

Comment: @mudasobwa it isn't. I believe this is mostly a jenkins question. I'm going to remove other tags

Comment: were you able to solve this one?

Answer (score 4):

Put `#!/bin/bash -l` as the first line of your script. It creates a login shell.

You could also source rvm first before calling `rvm use`:

`source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`